# Is the fuction $f(x) = \frac{7}{e^x - 2}$ continuous on the interval $ [-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, recreational-mathematics

Hi I am having trouble trying to figure this problem out. I have tried to separate the equation into a piece-wise function but was no help in making things clear. I am not sure if I use the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ since its in the interval given, or do something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Check if the denominator becomes equal to $0$ in the given interval: $$\begin{align*}e^x-2=0 &\iff e^x=2 \qquad \quad\mid \ln \\ &\iff \ln(e^x)=\ln2 \\&\iff x=\ln2\end{align*}$$ since $\ln$ and $e$ cancel out. Now, check whether $\ln 2 \in (-1, 1)$ or not and if yes, proceed as you know (with the limit).

Comment: Ok so i took the limit as x approaches ln2 and got 0 in the denominator. Does this mean that the function is not continuous between [-1,1], since the function is undefined there? Thank you for the response.

Comment: Yes, it is as you say it. The denominator becomes really small as you approach $\ln 2$ so the whole fraction explodes and becomes infinitely big.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** what happens when $x\rightarrow\ln 2$?

Comment: I am not sure. does the e and ln cancel out giving you x-2 in the denominator?

Comment: See @Stef's answer.